# TextView 3 dots show not correct

Tags: android

I want to use 3 dots on textview "**titleTextView**".

So here my xml layout

```
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/preview_bottom_container_height"
            android:background="@drawable/offer_rounded_corner_bottom_bg"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageViewPhoto"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageViewPhoto"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageViewPhoto">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/preview_title_margin_right"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/preview_title_margin_left"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/preview_title_margin_right"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/preview_title_margin_left"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@{LocalizedStringUtil.getLocalizedStringValue(item.name)}"
                android:textColor="#292929"
                android:textSize="@dimen/preview_offer_title_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/bottomContainer"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bottomContainer" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here result oh Android 6.0, diagonal 5.1
[image]
As you can see the 3 dots show correct. Nice.

But when I run on Android 4.4 , diagonal 5.0 I get the next result:
[image]

As you can see the 3 dots now show not correct (not same as on Android 6.0)

Why?

Comment: dont know what went wrong in your situation but insted of android:maxLines="1"     i have used singleLine = true  and work for me across all version

Comment: Yes this `android:singleLine="true"` fix the problem. But why? The properties: ":singleLine" is depricated.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try android:scrollHorizontally="true". If that doesnt do magic, try it with an linear/relative layout because maybe there is a problem with constraint in older android versions